# What is the philosophy of creating a database mapping tools?

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, mapping, entity-relationship

I'm new in the work with the Object Relational Mapping Tool's and I want to know what has caused the programming tools are created. What a privilege to work with the database and mapping tools will be for us?

Answer (score 1):

ORMs are used to close the gap between object-oriented models (applications) and the relational model (database). There are several difficulties for that mapping, like inheritance and object identification to name only a few (for example, check out http://www.cit.dk/cot/reports/reports/Case4/05-v1.1/cot-4-05-1.1.pdf to go on here).
There are many ORM implementations/frameworks that use different concepts to achieve the mapping and they offer different 'features'.

As you might know there are object-oriented database-systems too, but the relational model is still favored because of practical issues. For your application you could map the datamodel
on your own or (if available and it fits your needs) use an ORM.